# How to specify the parameter in a function can be nil in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I know we need to define the parameter of function in Swift to be neither implicit unwrapped optional or optional, to make it non-nil. However I am not sure what is more conventional between implicit unwrapped optional or optional.

I am watching **[WWDC 2014 Swift interoperability in depth](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/407xxptt888z5jv/407/407_hd_swift_interoperability_in_depth.mov?dl=1)** and a bit confused with two examples shown in the slides. Basically it is about whether we should use implicit optional or unwrap parameters when defining function.

---

### Example from Video

Below is the screenshot from that [WWDC 2014 Swift interoperability in depth](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/407xxptt888z5jv/407/407_hd_swift_interoperability_in_depth.mov?dl=1) (At 09:01)
[image]
And the quote from the speaker is

> You see again this is an implicit unwrapped optional, so that you can
>   pass a nil block in here.

Notice here both **url** and **completionHandler** are implicit unwrapped optionals, and we can pass in **nil** into it. All good!

---

### Example from Header file

**However** when I check **UIKit** UITableViewCell, I find most of the methods are defined with optional parameters, such as

```
    init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
```

And basically it is suggesting those parameters can be nil too.

Seems like both **?** and **!** try to suggest the same thing (it can be **nil**).

I understand that **?** means we will wrap whatever value to **optional** value (even for nil), and **!** means we will unwrap it if what is passed in is an **optional** value. But I am not sure whether we should use **!** or **?**. And which is conventional?

---

### Update

Looks like the video from WWDC 2014 is not quite correct or **out-dated**. Screenshot from the video shows **UIDocument** header file, which was different from the current UIKit header. It looks like at that time, all of them were defined as **!**. But now it is either **?** or plain type.

**WWDC 2014 Swift interoperability in depth (At 16:25)**

[image: Screenshot from WWDC]

**Current header file**

[image: Screenshot from current header file]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `?` is a shortcut for `Optional<T>` type
- `!` is a shortcut for `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<T>` type

Both types implement NilLiteralConvertible. This mean they have `init(nilLiteral: ())` and can be initialized by `Void`. This could be syntatically-sugard in code by compiler into regular assignement of `nil` to a `NilLiteralConvertible` variable. Here are some code lines that from compiler standpoint mean the same:

```
 let sweetOptionalInt: Int? = nil
 let semiSweetOptionalInt: Optional<Int> = nil
 let unsweetenedOptionalInt: Optional<Int> = Optional<Int>(nilLiteral: Void)
```

The same is true for `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional`.

So both could be initialized by `nil`, but behaviors of these types are different:

- `ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional` do unwrapping for you with an assumption
  when you do a call object is already provided (but could be nil
  before), so if it is not then application will crash with a runtime error.
- `Optional` will require you to provide information how to unwrap variables.

As for interoperability while ago Objective-C didn't have a way to express nullability of variables. This is why most of APIs was converted with ! that stands for "proceed further if you dare" Recently [Apple introduced](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25) nullability annotations for Objective-C. Apple augumented their APIs with these annotations, so now it is easier and safer to use methods with an extra nullability guidance in Swift.

Comment: I think this is closer to the truth. So what is the conventional way? Seems it was "!" before. But I guess it is "?" now.

Comment: If there are no new nullability keywords in ObjC used you should use ! as behavior is undefined and anything may happen. They augmented some of old APIs with nullability information, that is why now you some time see ? or no ? / ! at all.

Comment: @EthanFang check at the end of this article Apple explained how some APIs changed. What was before and what is now with new nullability annotations — https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=25

Comment: @EthanFang your update regarding changes in a signature absolutely correct. Nullability annotations were introduced just recently, so ObjC APIs converted as we speak.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the link. Now I get a deeper understanding!

Comment: Rule of thumb for a good Swift developer would be use "!" as less as possible in all the cases. Try to eliminate "!" if code allows as it is potential point of application crash.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't quite right. "!" is the "force unwrap" operator. It says "This is an optional, but I guarantee that when this code runs, it won't be nil." If you are wrong, you crash.

if you are writing a function that takes a parameter that can be legitimately nil, use "?", which makes it an Optional. Then in the code of your function, you have to handle the case where it is nil.

Comment: What how does "!" work when used to decorate a *parameter* type? It's surely not the same operator there ..

Comment: Thanks for your reply @duncan C. But please refer to the video I post above. I was under the exact same impression as you until I got confused.

Comment: As Nikita says in his answer, "force unwrapped" is better called implicitly unwrapped. That means that it can contain nil, but don't try to read the actual contents unless you're certain that it's not nil.